# Error: configuration failed for some packages, when installing package devtools

Tags: r, linux, ubuntu

I have R environment installed on my machine with Ubuntu 22.04, and I am trying to install R package "devtools" via `install.packages("devtools")`. I got the following error messages:

```
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘textshaping’
* removing ‘/home/jjt/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/textshaping’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘textshaping’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘textshaping’ is not available for package ‘ragg’
* removing ‘/home/jjt/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/ragg’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘ragg’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘ragg’ is not available for package ‘pkgdown’
* removing ‘/home/jjt/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/pkgdown’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘pkgdown’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘pkgdown’ is not available for package ‘devtools’
* removing ‘/home/jjt/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.1/devtools’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘devtools’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpGzS8N8/downloaded_packages’
```

What should I do to solve the issues? Thanks.

Comment: You could [r2u](http://eddelbuettel.github.io/r2u/) and rely on pre-made binaries for Ubuntu 22.04 "jammy". Works great for me and many others...

Comment: Else try the innermost package (first installation failure first, analyse _its installation error in isolation_ and fix it.  Tens of thousands of people use these packages on Ubuntu, and CRAN checks rigorously. You will be fine too -- but we need more detail than you show to say more.